# This is a sentence completion question

Tags: grammar

> "Had l realized what you intended,______________.
>
> A) I could do the right thing
>   B) I should not have wasted my time trying to explain the matters to you
>   C) I would tell hım what to do

I picked A but according  to my book right answer is B

Comment: According to me, all of them can work.  The question is pointless without more context.

Comment: This is the way they ask sentence completion question. It has short context  like that

Comment: These kind of questions test your ability to understand the people who make the tests.  In order to get a good score, you have to learn how they think, at least with regard to what they will say is "good English".  It has little if anything to do with how native speakers actually use English.  In this case, I would guess that B is the answer, because "you" is the object of both parts of the sentence.

Comment: Unless the book clearly explains *why* (giving some kind of criteria), I'd call exercises like this useless. Speaking purely stylistically, I could argue that picking B would lead to a sentence that is too long and difficult to parse.

Comment: However the language "I should not have wasted my time ..." is a fairly formal use of *should*, that is only used in certain dialects.  You would not hear it much in the US, for example.  Again, they're testing whether you can repeat what you've been *taught*, and not whether you can really speak English.

Comment: It is very helpful for this kind of question if you name the test or textbook

Comment: Jason Bassford , what is your aim ? I understood your first mark and editted it but your second mark is not fair . What l wrote was  the all of question    and l made necessary  explanation

Answer (score 1):

This question is about tense matching for an irrealis perfect conditional construction, also called [third conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Third_conditional).

We know it's third conditional because the condition, 'Had I realized what you intended', is formed in [past perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Past_perfect) with 'had'+verb.  A more common way to say this is 'If I had realized what you intended'.  Starting the sentence with 'Had' is less common than starting with 'If', but the grammatical construction and meaning is the same.  Starting with 'Had' may also imply a more formal tone.

Since the condition uses past perfect, the consequence should use [conditional perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_perfect) with 'would have'+verb.  In formal use, an additional form is acceptable, forming the conditional perfect tense with 'should have'+verb.  This consequence form using 'should have' is commonly paired with the condition form that starts with 'Had' instead of 'If'.  This is the form used in the accepted answer B.

Answers A and C are not acceptable in formal use, because they are not in conditional perfect. They are in simple past tense, which would be used for an irrealis conditional construction, also called [second conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_conditional_sentences#Second_conditional).  However, in real life outside of formal contexts, native speakers often mix and match tenses, and you might actually hear people use any combination of tenses.

Comment: I know thiy 3 type of conditional and it is used with could have v3 or would have v3 but l haven't come across 'should have v3'

Comment: Yeah, to me the 'should have' consequence form sounds rather stilted or outdated. I've seen it in modern use, but I wouldn't recommend using it. Note that this form simply means 'would' and does not have the usual meaning of 'should'. If you wanted to express the usual meaning of 'should' in the 3rd conditional consequence, you'd have to expand it into 'would have been supposed to' or something similar.